# How to Run control commands in KQL Function or any KQL Object

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

In extension to below url query ask.

[Query Optimization in KQL || Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208053/query-optimization-in-kql-pagination/78208141#78208141)

I am trying to execute Stored Query result in one go means like in Function or any other object in KQL

- Drop stored query results if exists.
- create stored query results.

When user or API submit query on ADX above two statement has be to execute so end user always get latest data else Stored Query Results valid for 24 hours but user always need latest query results on top of doing pagination.

I am trying below code but not able to achieve.

```
.create-or-alter function myfunction()
{

.drop stored_query_result my_stored_qry_res if exists

.set stored_query_result my_stored_qry_res with (previewCount = 20) <|
<select qry>

}
```

Dear KQL Experts, Please suggest me on this. Much appreciate for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Please see the first part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55387571

Comment: Thank you Yoni Sir. It means it is not possible to use control commands in function. thank you so much for your quick response and helping me.

Comment: @BrahmaiahTakkellapati  if you are using ADF and ADX, you might call an ADF pipeline via REST which executes both commands.